# Function that reads a string (.csv file name) and enters that file's data into a data frame object

Tags: r, function, csv

```
//function to enter .csv data
> data_entry <- function(NAME="filename.csv"){
+ dat <- read.csv(NAME)
+ }
> data_entry("data.csv")
> dat
```

When I enter this code, I get the following error:
    "object 'dat' not found"
Where did I go wrong?
P.S : I have placed "data.csv" in the required directory.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [R function not returning values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29570176/r-function-not-returning-values)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Objects created inside a function stay inside the function and are not exported into the global env, unless you `return` them, and assign the function result to a new name.

You should :

```
data_entry <- function(NAME="filename.csv"){
dat <- read.csv(NAME)
return(dat)
}

dat <- data_entry("data.csv")
dat
```

Comment: @Sricharan glad to be of help :) 
Don't forget to [accept the answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) if you found what you were looking for ;)